# Search Query display No Result in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Write Search Query for Displaying Matrimony Profiles. But It Does Not Display any Result. In this Query I Run in PHPMyAdmin Its Display 10 Results.

Please Suggest any Good Method to Solve this Error.

My code is Below

```
  if(!empty($items['search_profile_id'])){ //user first name
        $strCond = " and truematrimony_profile_id = '".$items['search_profile_id']."'";
        }

    if(!empty($items['gender'])){ 
            $strCond .= (!empty($strCond)) ? " and (gender = '".$items['gender']."')" : " and (gender = '".$items['gender']."')" ;
        } 

   if(!empty($items['caste'])){

        $strCond .= (!empty($strCond)) ? " and (caste_id != '".$items['caste']."')" : " and (caste_id != '".$items['caste']."')";

    } 

    if(!empty($items['education'])){

        $strCond .= (!empty($strCond)) ? " and (highesteducation_id = '".$items['education']."')" : " and (highesteducation_id = '".$items['education']."')";

    } 

    if(!empty($items['occupation'])){

        $strCond .= (!empty($strCond)) ? " and (occupation_id = '".$items['occupation']."')" : " and (occupation_id = '".$items['occupation']."')";

    } 

     if(!empty($items['complexion'])){

        $strCond .= (!empty($strCond)) ? " and (complexion_id = '".$items['complexion']."')" : " and (complexion_id = '".$items['complexion']."')";

    } 

   // echo $strCond;
    //exit;

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "SELECT * FROM #__truematrimony_profiles WHERE truematrimony_profile_id != '0' $strCond order by truematrimony_profile_id DESC LIMIT 10;";

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();

//$query->select('*');
//$query->from('#__truematrimony_profiles');   
//$query->where('truematrimony_profile_id != 0'.$strCond); 
//$query->order('truematrimony_profile_id DESC');
//$query->setLimit(15);
    //$db->setQuery($query);

    $profileinfo = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$profileinfo` is empty? Anyway remove the `$query->execute()` statement, it's already included in loadAssocList function